# How does laravel relate an actual table to the eloquent class?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

How does laravel  relate an actual table to the eloquent class ?
From what i understood is that the class name should be same as the table name but without the s
example 
Articles table the Eloquent class name is Article.
But what if the table name is Article or if there are 2 tables say Articles and article. 
How  does laravel assign the Eloquent class to the table ?

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#basic-usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If none is provided Laravel guesses the table name by lowercasing and pluralizing the model name. If you want to provide a specific table name, here is what you should do:

```
class Article extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'your_own_table_name';

    ...

}
```